# Excel 365 - Open csv files automatically (list separator solution not working)

Tags: excel

If I opened a csv file, Excel used to automatically format it into columns. At some point in the past Excel just stopped doing this.

I'm using Office 365 Business, Excel version 1803. Windows 10 ver 1709

I want to be able to double click on a csv file and have it open automatically formatted into columns.

This is not machine specific as my coworker has an identical issue on a different brand of computer.

So far I have tried the following:

- Changing the list separator: I cannot find the list separator setting in office 365, I think it may have been buried or removed.
- The "decimal separator" is a comma.
- Creating a simple csv to test with. I tested with this csv and it still has the same problem:

  Date,Count
  2018-01-02,22
  2018-01-03,24

  - I do know I can use text to columns and write macros to accomplish this. I want to avoid those if possible so I can just open a csv and it's formatted.

Thanks, any insights here would be great. I am really hoping it is some system or excel setting.

Comment: In what way did it "stopped doing this"? Are you seeing all data in the first column? It is difficult to solve problem when you have not explained the symptom. Does this help? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid "see all data in the first column", yes that's correct. It is not formatting the csv into different columns as it used to do and displays it all in one column.  Thanks for the link, I read through, but didn't find anything that resolves the situation.

I did check my OS region settings as the link advised, but the list separator is already a comma.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and I hope that 1 year and 10 months later it will still help somebody.
Had the same problem and solved it by "Change date, time or number formats" in the Control Panel.
Standard the Format is "Match Windows display language"
My Windows is in English (list separator = ",") but I live in Belgium where the list separator is ";"
So in formats, I changed the Format to "Dutch (Belgium)". That solved it for me.

Once you change your country, double-check in "Additional Settings" if the separator is what you want. Keep in mind that also other things might change, such as decimal symbol and digit grouping symbol.
If you don't want that, you might only want to change the separator and don't change the country.

Best regards,
Koen